# Sprite Kit Scene Editor GameScene.sks scene width and height

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using the spritekit scene builder to build my scene (aka the GameScene.sks file when you create the project in xcode 7 ios9). SpriteKit only uses pixel values when setting the screen height and width. My question is this:

If I set the pixels values to that of an iphone 6, will the game be too small for ipad and iphone 6+? Why is there no option to fit the device screen? What should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Pixel density

First of all the size of the Scene is defined in `Points` not `Pixels`.

Let's see how the devices that support iOS 9 deal with this:

> - **1 point = 1x1 pixel:** iPad 2, iPad mini
> - **1 point = 2x2 pixels:** iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6s, iPad mini 2, iPad mini 3, iPad mini 4, iPad 3,
>     iPad 4, iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro, iPod touch 5, iPod touch 6
> - **1 point = 3x3 pixels:** iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus

This allow you to specify a size that is automatically converted for the pixel density of a particular device.

### Screen size

There are several screen sizes available on the iPhone/iPad supported by iOS 9.

With SpriteKit you can easily face this problem setting the `scaleMode` property of your `Scene`.

You can chose among 4 options:

> - **Fill:** Scale the SKScene to fill the entire SKView.
> - **AspectFill:** Scale the SKScene to fill the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some cropping may occur if the view has a
>     different aspect ratio.
> - **AspectFit:** Scale the SKScene to fit within the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some letterboxing may occur if
>     the view has a different aspect ratio.
> - **ResizeFill:** Modify the SKScene's actual size to exactly match the SKView.

You probably want to set `AspectFill` but it really depends on your game.

To set the property open `GameViewController.swift` (or `.m` if you use Objective-C), in `viewDidLoad` you'll find this line. Just change it to mach your preference.

```
/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```