# Best way to define variables for node sizes on different screens in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in SpriteKit. I have different classes for different nodes I'm going to use in my scene. I need to make my game universal so it adapts to every screen. What is the best way to to define different variables that I'm going to use on different classes and on the main scene.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968046/sprite-kit-scene-editor-gamescene-sks-scene-width-and-height/33970677#33970677

Answer (score 0):

Then initializing your nodes you can create parameter of your `world` `SKNode` and then access your `world.frame.size`.

```
class NodeClass: SKSpriteNode {

    init(world: SKNode) {

        super.init(texture: nil, 
            color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: 
            CGSizeMake(world.frame.size.width / 24, world.frame.size.width / 24))
    }
}
```

Also you set `position` and movament, scaling dependant on your scene size.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define different element sizes for different screens. This will make everything much more complex on the long run.

### Thinking in Points (not Pixels)

Instead of thinking in terms of pixels, you should define sizes in terms of points.

Next in the `GameViewController` set the `scaleMode` of your scene to `.AspectFill`.

```
gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

This way the whole scene (and its content) will be automatically scaled to fill the current display. And you will not go crazy trying to manage different sizes for every element.