# Xcode SpriteKit how to adapt label in GameScene with different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

## I have a label in GameScene, there is no auto layout to use here, how I can use CGpoint to make sure this label stay at the same position on different screens.

[image]

### Below is the code where I put my score label

```
scoreLabel?.position = CGPoint(x: -size.width / 2 + 120, y: size.height / 2 - 150)
```

Comment: What game framework are you using?

Comment: SpriteKit @trojanfoe

Comment: I think what you are doing it correct.  Use a ratio of the screen for position and size of the label.

Answer (score 0):

```
let scoreLabel = //insert functionality of scoreLabel here

scoreLabel?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + //insert dimention, 
y: size.height + //insert dimension)

self.addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Comment: Hi @Gavin Wong, I tried your way, it works on one simulator, but does not apply to all different screen sizes. If you print out size.width and size.height, it is the same value on different simulators

Answer (score 0):

seeing your previous comment, I would suggest you use the following functions, which change the dimensions when they are run on different screen sizes:

```
AspectFill
AspectFit
ResizeFill
```

Here is a link that could help you on how to use these functions: [Sprite Kit Scene Editor GameScene.sks scene width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968046/sprite-kit-scene-editor-gamescene-sks-scene-width-and-height)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I put in my View Controller:

```swift
var h, w = 1000

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            w = view.frame.width / (view.frame.height / 1000)
            let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: w, height: h))

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        
    }
}
```

It's handy to know that I make the height of any device 1000. It's much easier to make it universal.

Then I place everything percentage-wise on the screen.

```swift
label.position.x = w/2
label.position.y = h/2

label2.position.x = w/2
label2.position.y = h/2 - 50
```

These lines of code will place 2 labels in the center of the screen. Even if you rotate your device, and even if you use different sized devices. That `- 50` I used will always stay the same.

My main takeaway: I create global states of the relative size of the screen.

Helpful tip: I always make my scene's anchor point to be `.zero`. That way, the min width and height are always 0, and the max height is always 1000.